# Why $\int_0^af(x)dx=\int_0^af(a-x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is it true that:

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^af(x)dx=\int_0^af(a-x)dx?
\end{equation*}

Because I know that:

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^af(x)\,dx=F(a)-F(0)~\text{and}~\int_0^af(a-x)\,dx=F(a-a)-F(a-0)=F(0)-F(a)
\end{equation*}

So I got: $F(a)-F(0)=F(0)-F(a)$ and that's not necessarily true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You neglected the chain rule: if
$$
\frac d {dx} F(x) = f(x)
$$
then
$$
\frac d {dx} F(a-x) = -f(a-x), \text{ not } f(a-x).
$$

Comment: i can't see why in your answer. because you have $+x$ not $-x$ so $dF(x-a)=+f(x-a)$. if it was $dF(-x+a)$ so i can see why.

Comment: @debi There is a typo, he meant $F(a-x)$ **not** $F(x-a)$.

Comment: thanks i understand my mistake in my algebra.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 7):

You set $x=a-u$. For $x=0 \Rightarrow u=a$ and for $x=a \Rightarrow u=0$.

$$dx=-du$$

So:

$$\int_0^a f(x)dx=\int_a^0 f(a-x)(-dx)=\int_0^a f(a-x)dx$$

Answer (score 4):

You can prove it by taking $y=a-x$ and $dy=-dx$,

$$
\int _0^a f(x)dx = \int _{a}^0f(a-y)(-dy) = \int _0^a f(a-y)dy 
$$
**Note:**  your second statement in the question is not true.

Comment: اسانترین روش اینه. +1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Take $y = a - x$ then $dy = -dx$ and $$- \int_a^0 f(y) dy = \int_0^a f(y) dy$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $u=a-x$, we have $du=-dx$, then
$$\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx=\int_{u=a}^{u=0}-f(u)du=-\int_a^0f(u)du=\int_0^af(u)du$$