# Integral Property: $\int^a_{0}f(x)dx=\int^a_{0}f(a-x)dx$ [Proof by definition of Riemann Sums]

Tags: calculus, integration

This link: [Why $\int_0^af(x)dx=\int_0^af(a-x)dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270326/why-int-0afxdx-int-0afa-xdx) addresses this question but I do not follow the proofs in the answers: Each proof starts off with variable $x$ but ends the right hand side with a different variable. How does that work? I can't find this discussed anywhere else on the internet.

For example, how do we get from 
$\int_0^a f(x)dx$ to $\int_a^0 f(a-x)(-dx)$?(I apology if I'm overlooking some silly thing but for some reason I am stuck):

Does anyone know the proof or where else I can find it? Also are there any special conditions on it?

$$\int^a_{0}f(x)dx=\int^a_{0}f(a-x)dx$$

Comment: One way to justify this is to remember that a definite integral represents the area under the curve.  Both of these integrals represent the same area under the curve, but the second one traces the area *backwards*.

Comment: @MichaelBurr do know of a source where I can look this up a little more in detail?

Comment: Take an example, for example, $f(x)=x^2$, let $a=5$; then graph $f(x)$ and $f(5-x)$.

Comment: When you're looking for a source, are you looking for a source that the definite integral is an area under the curve?  The area under the curve can be taken as the *definition* of the definite integral.

Comment: No, no I know that very well and I see your point geometrically. I was wondering about this particular property worked out algebraically. Anyhow I understand it both ways much better now. Thanks. But if you do know of a source I wouldn't mind

Comment: I don't have a source (but it should be in most standard calculus textbooks).  It is a geometric explanation of the $u$-substitution $u=a-x$.

Comment: Proof by Riemann sums: $a+b+c+\cdots+z=z+y+x+\cdots+a$.

Comment: @anon I understand what you are taking about but I was hoping some one do a slightly better and elaborate proof walking me through, though Im grateful for the answer below that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following perhaps groady argument shows that, using the definition of Riemann integrals, we have:

$$\int_0^af(x)\,dx=\int_0^af(a-x)\,dx$$

If we have a partition of $[0,a]$, say $0, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, a$, then there is a corresponding partition $0, a-x_n, a-x_{n-1}, \ldots a-x_n, a$, also of $[0,a]$.  The upper partial sums for the first integral in the first partition are
$$x_1\max_{0\leq x\leq x_1} f(x)+(x_2-x_1)\max_{x_1\leq x\leq x_2} f(x) +\ldots + (a-x_n)\max_{x_n\leq x\leq a} f(x)$$
The upper partial sums for the second integral in the second partition are
$$(a-x_n)\max_{0\leq x\leq a-x_n} f(a-x)+(x_n-x_{n-1})\max_{a-x_n\leq x\leq a-x_{n-1}} f(a-x) +\ldots \\+ (a-x_1)\max_{a-x_1\leq x\leq a} f(a-x)$$
We have
$$\max_{0\leq x\leq a-x_n} f(a-x)= \max_{x_n\leq x\leq a} f(x)$$
and similar equations for the other intervals making up the partitions.  We thus see that for each upper partial sum for the first integral, there is a corresponding and equal upper partial sum for the second integral.  The same is true for lower partial sums -- just replace max with min.  Thus, because the two Riemann integrals have the same collections of lower and upper partial sums, they must have the same value.

Comment: Yeah see this clears it up. The definition makes a lot more sense thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Good answers were already given. Let us look some pictures.

- $f(-x)$ is the reflection of $f(x)$ about the $y$-axis.

[image]

So, from geometric interpretation of integral, we "see" that
$$\int_{0}^af(x)\;dx=\int_{-a}^0f(-x)\;dx\tag{1}$$

- $f(a-x)$ is the horizontal translation $a$ units to the right of $f(-x)$ .

[image]

So,
$$\int_{-a}^0f(-x)\;dx=\int_{0}^af(a-x)\;dx\tag{2}$$

- From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$\int_0^af(x)\;dx=\int_{0}^af(a-x)\;dx$$

Comment: "*f(−x) is the reflection of f(x) about the y-axis*"- But won't that be true only for odd functions?

Comment: @MrReality Given $f:[0,a]\to\mathbb R$, the new function $g:[-a,0]\to\mathbb R$ defined by $g(x)=f(-x)$ is the reflection of $f$ about the y-axis. In my post, $f(-x)$ stands for $g$ (as well as $f(x)$ stands for the original function $f$ and $f(a-x)$ stands for the translation $g_a:[0,a]\to \mathbb R$ of $g$ defined by $g_a(x)=g(x-a)=f(a-x)$). It is an [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Functional_notation).

Answer (score 4):

Let $u=a-x$, we have $du=-dx$, then
$$\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx=\int_{u=a}^{u=0}-f(u)du=-\int_a^0f(u)du=\int_0^af(u)du$$
Since $\int_0^a f(x)dx=\int_0^a f(u)du$ (independent of the relationship between $x$ and $u$) we are done. This is because the variable of integration is a *dummy variable*

Intuitively, what's going on is we are reversing the order that we are looking at terms. Integrals are summations, and what this $u$-substitution highlights is the fact that when we look at $f(a-x)$ what we are really doing is changing the order in which we add up the terms.

Comment: "Since mathematics is invariant under change of notation", can you please explain this a little more. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't matter what symbols you use in an expression.... if you use $x$ or $y$ or $u$ or a small drawing of a house, the integral is still the same. Thus the integral on the right adds up to the same number as if it were written with $x$'s

Comment: Yes I understand that we can always use any variable, and we had used a, b or anything else is fine, but when we have already set $x = a -u$ shouldn't we follow suit when changing $x$ to $u$(because a relationship exists between them)

Comment: If you're still having trouble getting this, try drawing a picture. Shade in the areas computed by each integral

Comment: We do have that relationship, but it's irrelevant. If my comment is confusion, just ignore it. All I'm pointing out is that $\int f(u)du=\int f(x)dx$ no mater what the relationship between $u$ and $x$ is.

Comment: I see since in our substitution we have $u= a-x$ and $x=a-u$ $x$ and $u$ are used interchangeably therefore we they are in a sense the same variables right?

Answer (score 2):

Let $ u = a-x $.  Then $du = -dx$ and when $x = 0$, $u = a$ and when $x=a$, $u=0$.

Then write the second integral:
$$ \int_{x=0}^{x=a} f(a-x) \,dx = -\int_{x=0}^{x=a} f(u) \, du \\
= -\int_{u=a}^{u=0} f(u) \, du = \int_{u=0}^{u=a} f(u) \, du = \int_{x=0}^{x=a} f(x) \, dx
$$

The last step is just using a different symbolfor a "dummy variable".

Comment: Yes but that doesn't mean that $u = x$ ; we have taken $u = a - x$?

Comment: In the next to last integral, what we call "$u$" is irrelevant (as long as it does not match one of the variables appearing in the limits); for example, $\int_0^a f(x) \, dx = \int_0^a f(t) \, dt$ and so forth.  In fact, the point of the exercise was to get you used to manipulating the dummy integration variables in this way, so that in more complicated cases you are at least familiar with this technique.